# django.utils module import error in appengine 1.7.6

Tags: django, google-app-engine, python-2.5

I just updated to 1.7.6 appengine and started getting ImportError for django.utils, my app is using python 2.5 and had no issues running before this update.

Any idea if this was removed in the update?

```
line 1, in <module>
from django.utils import simplejson
ImportError: No module named django.utils
```

Comment: You should upgrade to 2.7..

Comment: @Lipis but it was working with 2.5 before i upgraded appengine to 1.7.6

Answer (score 1):

If you're not able to upgrade to 2.7, try using `old_dev_appserver.py` instead of `dev_appserver.py`.

Comment: I tried renaming old_dev_appserver.py to dev_appserver.py, but the AppEngine Launcher did not start the server