# New dev server not getting requests

Tags: google-app-engine

Updated to AE 1.7.6 and was using it with no issues until today. It appears the new dev server is no longer getting requests. When I run the dev server in Terminal I see no error message and everything appears to be working as usual. When I go to localhost:8080 I get a Chrome error page and no requests are logged in the Terminal.

If I run old_dev_server.py everything works as usual.

The only things I've done to my mac since I updated to 1.7.6 was restart and run a mac update for "MacBook Pro Retina SMC Update v1.1".

Any ideas?

Comment: check your appengine log, there might be an error, I'm experiencing similar issue after upgrading to 1.7.6 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15665779/django-utils-module-import-error-in-appengine-1-7-6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may be hitting a Chrome issue. See https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=224215.

As a workaround go to chrome://flags and set "Built-in Asynchronous DNS" to "Disabled", then restart the browser.